# How to Build a custom login and redirection form in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, json, ajax, wordpress

so i read this:
[wordpress custom form desc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) 
i have a web service api which i post username and password and it returns around 6-7 fields like address , phone number and so on .
i easily can put it to html action form and return the json encode style result but i don't know how to put it into word press 
so it works like this : 
i call a url and i post my user and pass , then when loged in sucsesfully another web service url which brings back data like :

```
{"result":"OK","credit":"0","email":"email","fn":"\u0633\u067e\u0647\u0631","ln":"\u0633\u062a\u0627\u06a9\u0647","phone":585848","NID":"541454156"}
```

so all i want to do for users to be able to login to www.example.com/login and after it should load this data :

```
{"result":"OK","credit":"0","email":"email","fn":"\u0633\u067e\u0647\u0631","ln":"\u0633\u062a\u0627\u06a9\u0647","phone":585848","NID":"541454156"}
```

in a styled page.
so few questions:
1.where should i put my web service url for calling ?
2.how can anyone get info from 3rd party url and put it to beautiful style page and redirect user after login in word press?
3.you know any plugin that can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add it by including template in the wordpress page ,